# Java/Spring - How to unit test a validation constrain when in method parameter

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Java, however Ill try to explain the situation as good as possible:
I have create a custom validation that I want to to be applied only when I call a method. Therefore the annotation in not within my object class, but on the method call. Let say I want to validate is a car is good holidays (i.e a car is good and valid by it self.. but when i add it on my holidays package it should not validate). If the story is not good its ok. I am trying to simplify here...

so I have a custom constrain that look like this @CheckCar(occasion=VACATIONS)

so when I call a method of Vacation CLASS to add car to vacations:

```
public class Vacation {

    ....

    public addVacationCar(@CheckCar(occasion=VACATIONS) Car mycar){

    }

    ....

}
```

the constrain works just fine in my Spring mvc application!

However it is unclear how to implement a unit test for my method in Spring. A normal unit test will ignore the constrains.

All I could find is how to validate when I instantiate an object but not when I only want to validate on a method call

Thanks in advance! appreciate any

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Comment: thank you, however my question is quite specific and I could not find the answer in the documentation.